# What is the most efficient way to execute raster stackApply function on very large files R?

Tags: r, date, maps, time-series, raster

I have a large `rasterstack` `A` created from `>11000` netCDF files with the following dimensions:

```
 library(raster) 
 library(zoo) 
 library(xts)

class       : RasterStack
dimensions  : 885, 184, 162840, 11712  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
```

Each layer in `A` (`dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-11-30 23:59:59"), by="30 mins",tz="GMT"`) 
represents a timestep (30mins). The task is to accumulate the time series which is at 30mins resolution to 6-hourly resolution. For a subset (144 files) of the files I can get the results within `20 minutes execution time` using:

```
dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-04-03 23:59:59"), by="30 mins",tz="GMT")
index=rep(seq(1,12,by=1),each=12)
ras <- setZ(A,dates)
sixh <- stackApply(ras,indices=index, fun=sum);
```

Doing the same thing on `A` takes forever. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this task on `A`?

The same holds for all other functions within raster such as t(A), flip(A)... etc. These functions get really slow when I use them on`A`.

I guess it can be faster to coerce `A` to an `array or data.table` and perform calculations on that then stack back to `rasterstack`. How can this be realized on such a large file?

Comment: After several trials this seems to speed up my task 10 times: `rasterOptions(format="CDF",overwrite=TRUE,maxmemory = 1e+09, chunksize=1e+08,progress="text",tmpdir="C:/DATA/mydata")
rasterTmpFile("clean_this_after_")`